# Convert Object array to List

Tags: java, android, list, listview

```
private Object loadXmlFromNetwork(String urlString) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
        InputStream stream = null;
        // Instantiate the parser
        StackOverflowXmlParser stackOverflowXmlParser = new StackOverflowXmlParser();
        List<StackOverflowXmlParser.Entry> entries = null;
```

populating entries with objects ad in the end

```
return entries
```

This method is returning there

```
protected List<StackOverflowXmlParser.Entry> doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {

            return loadXmlFromNetwork(urls[0]);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            mException = e;
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            mException = e;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Now i have to return the  List to method. 
How could i do that

Comment: Will any `List` whatever do?  Does it need to be modifiable?

Comment: You could use [Arrays.asList(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...))

Answer (score 1):

change the return type of your private method:

```
private List<StackOverflowXmlParser.Entry> loadXmlFromNetworkloadXmlFromNetwork(String urlString) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
```

and return the list:

```
return entries;
```

or make a cast:

```
  protected List<StackOverflowXmlParser.Entry> doInBackground(String... urls) {
    try {

        return (List<StackOverflowXmlParser.Entry>)loadXmlFromNetwork(urls[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected List<StackOverflowXmlParser.Entry> doInBackground(String... urls) {
    try {

        List<StackOverflowXmlParser.Entry> data = (List<StackOverflowXmlParser.Entry>) loadXmlFromNetwork(urls[0]);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        mException = e;
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        mException = e;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: that must results to "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to ..."

Comment: why is that ? Aren't they the same type ?

Comment: no. the private method returns Object and doInBackground has to deliver the List. thats not possible without cast or changing the return type of the method(s)

Comment: You're absolutely right, I totally missed that one.

Answer (score 0):

If method `loadXmlFromNetwork(String urlString)` is supposed to return a `List`, then you should update its return type to specify so.  Exactly how that might look depends on how you intend to use the return value, but most likely you just want

```
List<StackOverflowXmlParser.Entry> loadXmlFromNetwork(String urlString)  // ...
```

That method must then follow through on its declaration.  It already returns a reference that has the correct type, but for your method to be useful, you must initialize local variable `entries` as a reference to a suitable `List`, and populate that list with the desired entries.  Possibly that would start something like this:

```
entries = new ArrayList<>();
```